# Getting individual string length in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to write a program which does the following:

There is a method called `lengthOffTheWords`. It receives an array of strings, and returns an array of numbers which represent the length of each individual string.

Ex: For the following input

`{"I", "know", "a" , "friend"}` the method returns `{1,4,1,6}` .

`{"yes"}` the method returns `{3}.`

`{"me", "too"}` the method returns `{2,3}.`

I would like to see an example of how to write it.

Comment: Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: array.Select(x => x.Count())

Comment: I will answer this question but next time make sure you do some research before you ask.

Comment: @Najera - `Count` is inefficient if the input is a `string`, use `Length` instead.

Comment: Your question is really poorly written. Take your time to read SO rules before posting. Anyway the suggestion from @Najera is the right solution, replacing the Count() with Length.

Comment: I know, But i think he should know about those extension methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int[] GetLengths(string[] array)
    {
       int[] structure = new int[array.Length];
       for(int i = 0;i < array.Length;i++)
        {
           int length = array[i].Length;
           structure[i] = length;
        }
        return structure;
    }
```

Comment: This is as bad as the question. A simple myArray.Select(c => c.Length) will do. No need to do any loop. Plus your answer doesn't generate an array with the lengths, it just creates a local variable in each iteration with the length.

Comment: Oh wow. *Claps slowly*

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question though does it?..

Comment: Yes it does but obviously you are just trying to be smart. he is given an array of 3 strings and he wants to have the length of each of the strings as an output.

Comment: It's not fancy but it does the job. If this added the lengths to an array and returned it, you would probably end up with very similar IL after compilation. Everything does not have to be LINQ, but it does make it prettier. If you wanted to be super clever you could write is as an extension method, how about that!

Comment: @CodingChief your [original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27863562/1) did not answer the question.  Your revised answer does.  It's not a matter of whether LINQ was used or not.

Comment: Why are you arguing over my answer for a question about putting string lengths in an array. I gave him an answer about how to retrieve the individual lengths which is the only reason why this question was asked in the first place. Have a nice day I'm done.

Comment: @CodingChief We're all just trying to help. You got a +1 from me for your revised answer. I think there's value in understanding what LINQ is essentially doing under the covers.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the answer by Coding Chief is the one which I used.

Comment: Just to irritate people, here's another non-LINQ answer: `string[] words = { "I", "know", "a", "friend" };` `int[] wordLengths = Array.ConvertAll(words, delegate(string x) { return x.Length; });` +1 to Coding Chief for revising his answer to a complete one, and for the use of a _slow clap_.  It can get pretty rough in the SO waters, gotta love the use of comedy.

Answer (score 7):

I would do something like this:

```
public int[] LengthOffTheWords(string[] array)
{
     return array.Select(item => item.Length).ToArray();
}
```

I did not test this but it should do what you want.